# Is there a way to get data from two pivot tables in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I’ve next database structure:

```
friends:
id,
first_name,
last_name,
```

```
friends_activities:
friend_id,
user_id,
type (enum),
created_at,
```

```
friends_reactions:
friend_id,
user_id,
type (enum),
```

And I need to count all friends_reactions and friends_activity together as e.g. engagements_count.

So far I’ve created eloquent relationship in the Friend.php model:

```
public function reactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FriendsReaction::class);
}

public function activities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FriendsActivity::class);
}
```

And for now, I’m getting them with:

```
$friends = Friend::query()->withCount('activities', 'reactions')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id());

        switch ($request->input('status')) {
            case FriendStatus::Active->value:
                $friends->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Whitelisted)
                    ->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Unfriended)
                    ->havingRaw('activities_count + reactions_count > 0');
                break;
            case FriendStatus::Inactive->value:
                $friends->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Whitelisted)
                    ->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Unfriended)
                    ->havingRaw('activities_count + reactions_count = 0');
                break;
            default:
                $friends->where('status', $request->input('status'));
                break;
        }

        if ($search = $request->input('search')) {
            $friends->whereRaw("(CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE ?)","%$search%");
        }

        if ($request->input('sortBy') && $request->has('sortType')) {
            switch ($request->input('sortBy')) {
                case 'name':
                    $friends->orderByRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) {$request->input('sortType')}");
                    break;
                case 'engagements_count':
                    $friends->orderByRaw("activities_count + reactions_count {$request->input('sortType')}");
                    break;
                default:
                $friends->orderBy($request->input('sortBy'), $request->input('sortType'));
                break;
            }
        }

        return $friends->paginate($request->input('perPage', 10));
```

Do you know how to pull the activities and reactions together as `engagements` (activities + reactions) via eloquent withCount (eager loaded of course)?

Comment: are your table relationships like this friends has many activities and reactions, activities and reactions belong to friends? but I see the user_id so is it that the reactions and activities are many-to-many between user and friends

Comment: They are not actual relationships, I mean I didn't create FK for them. 

Yes, they are like many-to-many between friends and users.

Comment: what is the difference between activities and reactions? I think you can have one table and if you want a distinction from the data you can use a status activity for some data then reaction for other based on how you want it to be

Comment: okay if they are many-to-many then you can use ```public function friends(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Friend::class, 'friends_activities');
    }

 public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends_activities');
    }```  but you need one table. the you will be able to use withCount and sort etc.

Comment: I'm sure you can use both of them activi... and reac.. as long as you change the function names

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use them with two tables because the data is not the same. In activities, there is possible to be more records with other types while in reactions there is available only one type per user, friend record.

I've updated the whole query above so you could have a better picture.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would define an Accessor on your `Friend` model:

```php
class Friend extends Model {
  protected function engagements(): Attribute {
    return Attribute::make(
      get: fn () => $this->activities_count ?? 0 + $this->reactions_count ?? 0
    );
  }
}
```

Then, as long as you include `withCount(['activities', 'reactions'])` in your Query, you'll be able to do something like this:

Controller Code:

```php
$friends = Friend::withCount(['activities', 'reactions'])
->where('user_id', auth()->id())
->get();

return view('example')->with(['friends' => $friends]);
```

In your View:

```
@foreach ($friends as $friend)
  {{ $friend->engagements }}
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: This works for listing, but it doesn't work for sorting and having clauses.

`$friends->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Whitelisted)
                    ->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Unfriended)
                    ->having('activities_count', '>', 0)
                    ->orHaving('reactions_count', '>', 0);`

I need it more for that purpose to replace here these having with only one `->having('engagements', '>', 0);`
and to be able to sort by `engagements` or `engagements_count`.

Answer (score 0):

This old way but work for me.

```
class Friend extends Model {
  public function reactions(){
    return $this->hasMany(FriendsReaction::class);
  }

  public function activities(){
    return $this->hasMany(FriendsActivity::class);
  }

  public function getCount(){
      return count($this->reactions() + $this->activities());
  }
}
```

and use it

```
$friends = Friend::where('user_id', auth()->id())->first();
$friends->getCount();
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but only for listing. You can't use it in sorting or having clauses. Similar behavior to the above answer.

Comment: I think you should go check https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models-on-morph-to-relationships

Comment: Thank you, but it's not related to the morph relationships. It's hasMany but with two tables.

Comment: have you try $friends = Friends::query()->whereHas('activities' , null, '>', 0)
        ->orWhereHas('reactions', null, '>', 0)->get();  its work for me on query $blabla->having('activities_count', '>', 0)                     ->orHaving('reactions_count', '>', 0);

Comment: If I try it like this:

$friends->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Whitelisted)
                    ->where('status', '!=', FriendStatus::Unfriended)
                    ->whereHas('activities_count', '>', 0)
                    ->orWhereHas('reactions_count', '>', 0);

I got this error:
Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::whereHas(): Argument #2 ($callback) must be of type ?Closure, string given

Comment: ya, in my case just type null. ->whereHas('activities' , null, '>', 0) ->orWhereHas('reactions', null, '>', 0)

Comment: It's working. Thank you, it's not an answer that I'm trying to accomplish but it's an optimized query than the original one. It's better to have where clauses instead of having.

Comment: Actually, I can't use `whereHas` because it includes all rows ignoring user_id. Thank you anyway.